# Categories As clickable buttons Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a view to render a list of all unique categories. I want them to be links. that open a new view displaying all items belonging to that category. i have no idea how to create those links on the urlpatterns.
I also have some questions regarding  what is the best course of action on this. the first thing I have tryed is having my model  already include the category field  and filter unique fields on  my ListView class. second thing i tryed  is to create a new model to contain all categories.

my models.py

```
class Items(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codigo_proveedor = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    # categoria = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey('Categorias', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    c_minima = models.IntegerField()
    c_actual = models.IntegerField()
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey('Proveedores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + '   -----   ' + str(self.categoria) + '   -----    ' + str(self.c_actual)

class Categorias(models.Model):
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    # slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    active =  models.BooleanField()

    #
    # def get_absolute_or_url(self):
    #   return '',(self.slug, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoria


class Proveedores(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    direccion1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    direccion2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    active =  models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.nombre
```

my views.py

```
# CREA LOS BOTONES DE CLASIFICACIONES
# class ItemListView(ListView):
#     model= Items
#
#     def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
#         context = super(ItemListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
#         context['categoria'] = Items.objects.all().order_by('categoria').values('categoria').distinct()
#         return context


class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Categorias

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ItemListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categoria'] = Categorias.objects.all().order_by('categoria')
        return context
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In `categorias_list.html` create your links

```
   {% for obj in object_list %}
      <a href="{% url 'cat' obj.id %}">{{ obj.categoria }}</a>
   {% endfor %}
```

In `urls.py` create your URLs

```
 url(r'^categoria/(?P<pk>[0..9]+)/$', views.CategoriaDetail.as_view(), name='cat')
```

In `views.py` create the detail view for a Categoria

```
class CategoriaDetail(DetailView):
    model = Categorias
```

In `categorias_detail.html` display the items

```
{% for item in obj.iterms_set.all %}
   {{ item.descripcion }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi i implemented the solution you provided me and i get `NoReverseMatch at /displayCategory/`
`Reverse for 'cat' not found. 'cat' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: got it this did the trick 
`url(r'^displayCategory/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.CategoriaDetail.as_view(), name='cat'),`